# How to count the number of subarrays within a bigger array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

How can you get a subarray from a bigger array recursively, and without using copyOfRange?

For example if `int[] a = {1,2,1,3,1,2,1,1,2}`, and `int[] b = {1,2}`, the correct answer is 3.
This is the only recursive call I have, but I'm not sure what to do beyond this.
I know the base case should be `if(a.length < b.length)`, but I don't understand how to count the occurrences.
The function returns `return numSubstring(a,b,low, mid-1) + numSubstring(a,b, mid+1,high);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static int countSubs(int [] data, int [] sub) {
    int cnt = 0;
    if (data.length < sub.length) {
        return cnt;
    }
    boolean found = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != sub[i]) {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        cnt++;
    }
    
    cnt += countSubs(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 1, data.length), sub);
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Note: I left an intentional flaw with this code.  You don't actually want to use the Arrays.copyOf() in this use-case because it could get very expensive for large arrays.  What you'll actually want to do is pass an index into the method and increment it with each recursion.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense!